# UISlider as UICollectionViewListCell accessory running off edge of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration, uilistcontentconfiguration

Does anyone know why my UISlider runs off the edge of my list cell? I am configuring it as a custom accessory.

Code:

```
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String>.init { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        config.text = itemIdentifier
        cell.contentConfiguration = config
        let sliderAccessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: .init(customView: UISlider(), placement: .trailing()))
        cell.accessories = [sliderAccessory]
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you have to set `maintainsFixedSize` to `true` and `reservedLayoutWidth` to `actual`. Define the width of the slider in the slider's `init(frame:)` initializer.

```
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String>.init { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        var config = ...
        let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 80))
        let sliderAccessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: .init(customView: slider, placement: .trailing(), reservedLayoutWidth: .actual, maintainsFixedSize: true))
        cell.accessories = [sliderAccessory]
    }
```